# Clash of Clans multiple accounts?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Can I keep multiple accounts in my same android device? I tried several times signing a different google account in COC. I could log in using a different google account but a no new village would load. Also my Google Play Sign-In button remains red. What went wrong? Any idea how can I get a new village using the new account?

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically yes you could do it, but it is in violation of Super Cell's terms of service and is bannable.

> The Service supports only one Account per game on a supported device.

- Source: [SuperCell-Terms of Service](http://supercell.com/en/terms-of-service/)

So it is possible to have multiple accounts on one device but the action is not allowed by SuperCell and can lead to bans.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one way is adding multiple google accounts which have a clash village synced to it. Disconnecting and reconnecting with another account will allow you to switch your village.

However, this is often an inconvenience so another way is to download and application of the app store such a parallel space which allows two instances of one app on a device. This would allow the original clash app to be signed into your main village while the duplicate parallel space clash app can be signed into another google account removing the issue of singing in and out.